# Azure Storage with NestJS - save and fetch file with metadata

Tags: typescript, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, nestjs

I am using Azure Storage within my NestJS project. Uploading of files works fine, but I can't successfully solve how to upload files with custom meta and read this file by name.

As you can see I overwrite `originalname` with uuid to make sure this file name stays unique. this uuid I am next using as reference for the saved file. Due to overwriting original name, I lost information about real file name, which I want to store as meta information.

```
async uploadFile(file: UploadedFileMetadata): Promise<void> {
    await this.azureStorageService.upload({
      ...file,
      originalname: getUuid(),
    })        
}
```

`azureStorageService` doesn't have any other useful methods, can you tell me how to save file name to meta and then read this meta by saved uuid to download this file? Thank you

Comment: How's going? Has your issue got solved?

Answer (score 2):

You are right, I have reviewed the source code of `azureStorageService`, there are no other useful methods. But luckily, it will reply a `storageUrl` with SAS token, so with it, we could make another HTTP request to call this [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/set-blob-metadata) to set blob metadata.
This is my test code:

```
  @Post('azure/upload')
  @UseInterceptors(
    AzureStorageFileInterceptor('file', null),
  )
  async UploadedFilesUsingInterceptor(
    @UploadedFile()
    file: UploadedFileMetadata,
    ) {
      file = {
        ...file,
        buffer : Buffer.from('file'),
        originalname: 'somename.txt'
      };
      const storageUrl = await this.azureStorage.upload(file);
      //call rest api to set metadata
      await this.httpService.put(storageUrl + "&comp=metadata",null,{headers:{'x-ms-meta-name':'orginal name here'}})
      .subscribe((response) => {
        console.log(response.status);
      });
   {
    Logger.log(storageUrl);
  }}
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: thank you, I solve it by db table where I place my file metada, but looks also nice

Comment: @DenisStephanov. thanks for your reply and glad to know you have solved your issue. So if it could be another way to solve your issue, could you please mark it as an answer so that it will help others?